# sample code for overflow in stack

Tags: linux

Hello
Can you give me a sample code for overflow in stack with c or .net ? and say me how do you resolve this bug.

Thank you

Comment: The resolution is easy. Just don't do whatever the sample does.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
static void f(void) {
    f();
}
int main (void) {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

That should give you a very nice stack overflow, the solution to which is: don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>

void function( char *str ) {
   char buf[8];

   strcpy(buffer,str);
}

void main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  function( argv[1] );
}
```

Classic example. strcpy() copies without checking any sizes. So, if your source string (str) is bigger than the buffer (buf) you will get a buffer overflow. Making it say 16chars you will get a stack overflow.

You can resolve this bug by using a safer function like strncpy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean running out of stack space, or doing something malicious?

The classic article on overflowing the stack maliciously:

http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

If you mean just running out of stack space, all you need to do is have a recursive function that ends up allocating too much space on the stack, and running out:

```
int foo()
{
    int something = 4;
    foo();
    return something; /* Yeah, we never get here */
}
```

Comment: Technically, that's a buffer overflow rather than a stack overflow, but it's a damn good article nonetheless.

Comment: i dont think he means buffer overflow, but thanks for posting that article!  i hadnt seen it before

Comment: He said stack ... I just edited with a recursive func that will eventually run out.

Answer (score 0):

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    if (x == 1 || x == 0) return 1;
    return factorial(x-1) * x;
}

factorial(-1);
```

Make sure recursive functions always reach a base case somehow.

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    if (x < 0) return 0;
    if (x == 1 || x == 0) return 1;
    return factorial(x-1) *x;
}

factorial(-1);
```

Comment: This will not recurse forever.

Comment: Ooh, good catch, @Ignacio. jon_d, you should use `==` rather than `=` :-)

Comment: Actually, it may not overflow anyway if tail end recursion optimisation happens. But, then again, my answer could have the call to `f()` optimised out of existence since it does nothing :-)

Comment: figured id make it non-trivial while i was at it